# Spring boot Maven rpm

Tags: maven, spring-boot, rpm

I have a spring boot application. Today maven creates jar out of the project. Below is my build section of pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>xsmartadapter</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

With adding below in the above build section I'm able to generate rpm.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.5</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <id>generate-rpm</id>
              <goals>
                  <goal>rpm</goal>
              </goals>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      </execution>
  </executions>
    <configuration>
      <group>Application</group>
      <packager>SWWDC</packager>
      <mappings>
          <mapping>
              <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
              <sources>
                  <source>
                      <location>target/classes</location>
                  </source>
              </sources>
          </mapping>
      </mappings>
      <name>xsmartadapter</name>
      <executable>rpmbuild</executable>
      <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when I try to install and start the service `sudo service 'name' start`. It says service not found.

But when I create a `tar.gz` file and generate a `rpm` using `rpmbuild -ba target/filename.spec` I'm able to start the service.

My goal is to generate a `rpm` (out of maven), install it and start the service.

Please provide some suggestion.

Comment: This is just a guess: You bind the `rpm` goal to the `pre-package` phase. This means that your rpm is built _before_ the jar file is generated (which happens in the `package` phase). Can you try to change the phase from `pre-package` to `package` and see if this works?